# Divide UV Textures for each Material

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake textures of a single object with two materials on it.
I want to pass that object into Unity and have two different materials associated with it.

I've looked but all I seem to find is How to bake multiple materials into one UV and I don't believe that's what I'm looking for...

To explain my question, here's an example:
Let's say I have this object with two different materials.
[image]
[image]

I want to pass this object to Unity with several maps, such as color/diffuse, roughness, metallic and normals.

But, I want two different materials, one for each color in this object, and the other corresponding
maps.

How would I do it?

I'm sorry if it is a newbie question but I'm honestly just trying to understand it.

Have a nice one!

Comment: You have to add a texture node with an image in the shader editor when bake a texture. If you add different for each material it will bake independently from each other.

Comment: @FFeller Hello there!

Thanks for the answer! I'm doing that right now but I think it won't work again. I can't add printscreens to comments but I'm doing it right now, baking atm